# Create a dynamic list of buttons from a template with unique onclick parameters

Tags: javascript, html, templates, button

Hello benevolent internet strangers! I'm a js rookie transferring from c#, and have struggled for days with something that really shouldn't be all that difficult. My intentions are as stated in the headline and my impotent code is as follows:

```js
function Create_button () {
    let temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
    clon = temp.cloneNode;
    clon.onclick = someFunction(someparam);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="Test3.js"></script>

<button onclick="Create_button()">New</button>

<div id="entry_list">
</div>

<template>
    <button>Alert</button>
</template>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can appreciate your ambition to start learning JavaScript. I would recommend you to pick up on a modern front-end framework along the way, like VueJS. If I understood your challenge correctly, you want to create a method to dynamically add buttons with custom handlers. You can check it out in the added snippet. Good luck on your path to learning JavaScript!

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
    <div @click="addButton">Add button</div>
    <div v-for="(button, index) in buttonsWithData">
      <button @click="button.handler">{{ button.name }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        message: "Hello Vue!",
        buttonsWithData: [
          {
            name: 'foo',
            value: 42,
            handler: () => { console.log('some handler') }
          }
        ],
        buttons: [
          () => {
            console.log("first");
          },
          () => {
            console.log("second");
          },
          () => {
            console.log("third");
          }
        ]
      },
      computed: {
        buttonCount: function() {
          return this.buttons.length
        }
      },
      methods: {
        addButton: function() {
          this.buttons.push(() => {
            console.log(`button ${this.buttonCount}`)
          })
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @phn, this is almost what I'm looking for (I'm sorry if my question was unclear!). Do you know how I could store a variable to use as a parameter within the button itself? I have a list of data and want each button to display certain strings and numbers. Your aid is much appreciated :)

Comment: @Rexor4321 You're welcome, thanks for considering my suggestion. Be aware the snippet I provided is dependent on VueJS (see the script tag in the header). I will give an updated example in the snippet in my answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought I could simply copy the code into my editor (just found out it looks completely different when I run it from this page). I'll read up on Vue and see if I can make it work in my project. Thanks again, and have an impeccable day!

Comment: Good luck, I hope I could assist you a little bit. If it's a HTML file you can copy this in the header:
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>`
and you need to copy the additional script with the `new Vue` declaration somewhere low in the body. Watch out with Razor syntax (when working in a AWS.NET project) as I recall it also uses `{{}}` declarations to generate HTML.